# Socket TimeOutException-Connection timed out

Tags: java, tomcat, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to connect with Tomcat Server(IP address-192.168.1.120 which is stored in Config.java(static variable APP_SERVER_URL)) but it is giving me socket timeout exception .

How to resolve it.Please help.

But when I

```
public class ShareExternalServer {

  public String shareRegIdWithAppServer(Map<String, String> paramsMap) {

    String result = "";

    try {
      URL serverUrl = null;
      try {
        serverUrl = new URL(Config.APP_SERVER_URL);
      } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        Log.e("AppUtil", "URL Connection Error: "
            + Config.APP_SERVER_URL, e);
        result = "Invalid URL: " + Config.APP_SERVER_URL;
      }

      StringBuilder postBody = new StringBuilder();
      Iterator<Entry<String, String>> iterator = paramsMap.entrySet()
          .iterator();

      while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Entry<String, String> param = iterator.next();
        postBody.append(param.getKey()).append('=')
            .append(param.getValue());
        if (iterator.hasNext()) {
          postBody.append('&');
        }
      }
      String body = postBody.toString();
    Log.d("&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&",body);
      byte[] bytes = body.getBytes();
    HttpURLConnection httpCon = null;
      try {
        httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) serverUrl.openConnection();

        httpCon.setDoOutput(true);
        httpCon.setUseCaches(false);
         httpCon.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(bytes.length);
       httpCon.setRequestMethod("POST");
        httpCon.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
            "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
        httpCon.setConnectTimeout(20000);
        OutputStream out = httpCon.getOutputStream();
        out.write(bytes);
        out.close();

        int status = httpCon.getResponseCode();
        Log.d("$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$",String.valueOf(status));  
    /*     if (status == 200) {
          result = "RegId shared with Application Server. RegId: "
              + regId;
        } else {
          result = "Post Failure." + " Status: " + status+regId;
        }*/
      } finally {
        if (httpCon != null) {
          ((HttpURLConnection) httpCon).disconnect();
        }
      }      

    } catch (IOException e) {
      result = "Post Failure. Error in sharing with App Server.";
      Log.e("AppUtil", "Error in sharing with App Server: " + e);
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

Comment: is your server running on the ip address mentioend and what is the port? is it running on the http port 80/ https port 443. If your tomcat application is running on a different port u need to add it.

Comment: Another alternative is to check whether the service is reachable using telnet <ip address> port

Comment: sometimes connection estabilishes but most of time it gives socket timeout exception-connection time out

Comment: How about using ping to check whether there is a network loss. Say try ping <ip adddress> -n 50, and check whether there is any network loss. ie how many packets are successful. As you said sometime it connects, it looks to be a network issue.